# Display value for specific table row only in *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I am trying to display a value for a specific table row however the value is getting displayed for every single row. I am using angular-data-tables.

Here is my code

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i=index" (click)="getCustomerAccounts(item)">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.href}} 
      <tr>
        <div class="card" *ngIf="msgFound">
          <div class="card-body">
            {{msgFound}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </tr>
    </td> 
</tr>
```

So the msgFound value is getting repeated in every row. Here is a screen shot of the problem
[image]

The code which generates msgFound looks like this. It basically allows the user to click on a row and if the row value matches a value in a JSON file then msgFound or msgNotFound is assigned a value.

```
  getBillingCycles() {
    this.BillingCyclesService.getBillingCycles()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.billingLink = data;
      this.billing = data._links.self;
    });
  }

  getCustomerAccounts(selectedItem: any) {
    this.CustomerAccountsService.getCustomerAccounts()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.customerAccounts = data;
      this.customerAccounts._embedded.accountList.forEach(longLink => {
          if (longLink.link.href.indexOf(selectedItem.href) != -1) {
            this.msgFound = longLink.accountNumber;
          } else {
            this.msgNotFound = 'No match for ' + selectedItem.href
          }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: at what condition do you want to restrict `msgFound` visiblity?

Comment: Sorry, when a user clicks on a row, it will render a value to msgFound. So I want only the clicked row to show the value. I will edit my question with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do here is set your index. The easiest way to do this would require to give the index from the html to your component:

`(click)="getCustomerAccounts(item, i)"`

And in your component something like:

```
getCustomerAccounts(selectedItem: any, index: number) {
  //http call and after
  if (longLink.link.href.indexOf(selectedItem.href) != -1) {
     this.msgFound = { value: longLink.accountNumber, index: index};
  } else {
     this.msgFound = { value: 'No match for ' + selectedItem.href, index: index};
  }
```

Now you need a little change in your html:

```
<div class="card-body" *ngIf="msgFound !== undefined && i === msgFound.index">
  {{msgFound.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting index of undefined

Comment: @skydev Edited the example. It's cause you have not set msgNotFound yet. `*ngIf="msgFound !== undefined && i === msgFound.index"` It will be set after the click.

Comment: it's not giving error anymore but when I click the row with matching data it does not do anything

Comment: Ahh I see the differents now might want `this.msgFound = { value: 'No match for ' + selectedItem.href, index: index};` or edit you html with adding:
`<div class="card-body" *ngIf="msgNotFound !== undefined && i === msgNotFound.index">
  {{msgNotFound .value}}
</div>` You probably click one that tiggered msgNotFound and then nothing will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If you define msgFound like that, datatable don't know what is the row it have to display. 
We have to use simple logic for that.

**First change your getCustomerAccounts Method as follows**

```
 getCustomerAccounts(item : any ,i: any) {
       this.CustomerAccountsService.getCustomerAccounts()
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.customerAccounts = data;
            this.customerAccounts._embedded.accountList.forEach(longLink => {
                 if (longLink.link.href.indexOf(selectedItem.href) != -1) {
                      this.mf.data[i].msgFound  = longLink.accountNumber;
                 } else {
                      this.msgNotFound = 'No match for ' + selectedItem.href
                 }
            });
         });
       }
```

If you already created class for **mf.data** Variable Add msgFound attribute to it also.

**Then change your html code as follows**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i=index" (click)="getCustomerAccounts(item,i)">
<td>{{i+1}}</td>
<td>{{item.href}} 
  <tr>
    <div class="card" *ngIf="item.msgFound">
      <div class="card-body">
        {{item.msgFound}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card" *ngIf="!item.msgFound">  <--! to proper format table. otherwise table will not align-->
      <div class="card-body">
        -
      </div>
    </div>

  </tr>
</td>
```

There is inbuilt advanced options in angular datatables. 
Refer this url : [Angular datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only using a single key `msgFound` it cannot distinguish which `item` should be displayed. If you should limit it to a specific row only, there must be some logic to tie it to `item`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can have a local variable that on click will toggle the `msgFound` property, can you check the below stackblitz, if it helps you!

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let item of data; let i=index; let display = false;" (click)="display = true;">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.href}} 
      <tr>
        <div class="card" *ngIf="item.msgFound && display">
          <div class="card-body">
            {{item.msgFound}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </tr>
    </td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

<kbd>**StackBlitz**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Just check the position in array of the row you want to display value, after apply the on the id of the row. You can do that with a simply if.

HTML: Use the i of let i = index

```
*ngif(check(i))
```

TS: Just check if the row.id is equal to the row you want to use

```
check(i){ 
if(i == 4) {
return true;
}
return false;
```

Here the code

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of data; let i=index; let display = false;" (click)="display = true;">
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.href}}
            <tr>
        <p *ngIf="check(i)">here i am</p>
                <div class="card" *ngIf="item.msgFound && display">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        {{item.msgFound}} 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  data = [
    {href: "adsfasdfasdf", msgFound: "asdfasdfasdf"},
    {href: "asdfasdf", msgFound: "asdfasdf"},
    {href: "adsfasdfazxcvzxcvsdf", msgFound: "zxcvzxcv"},
    {href: "adsfasdfaszxcvzxdf", msgFound: "asdfaszxcvzxcvdfasdf"},
    {href: "adfdhdfghsfasdfasdf", msgFound: "asdfasdfadhgfhsdf"}, 
  ];

  check(i){
    if(i === 3) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```